# Why are EJBs thread safe and servlets not ?

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, thread-safety, ejb

As per my understanding, a servlet container creates limited instances of servlets and multiple threads of each servlet instance and reuse those threads and instances.

Because there are multiple instances of a thread, they are not "Thread-safe" (though I understand that coding them with Thread-safety is not difficult).

EJBs containers on the other hand do not create threads of EJB, but reuse EJB objects only (using pool). Since there are no multiple threads of an EJB instance, there's no question of thread safety.

My question: Why have different behavior? Is it not a good idea to make EJBs work as Servlets (thread unsafe)?

I'm sure I'm missing something and want to understand that missing part.

Comment: Why should they be consistent? They do completely different things.

Comment: @EJP, Right, they do solve different purpose, but they have similarity in terms of statelessness. With this similarity, EJBs could have made more performance effective by have threads instead of having just the instances.

Comment: If you're interested in one servlet / one instance things - you take a look this post: http://piotrnowicki.com/2012/04/one-servlet-instance-to-rule-them-all/

Comment: They also have differences in terms of how they are implemented; how many instances are constructed by the container; what their respective specification say; etc. etc. All this fundamentally determines the lack of 'consistency' you are asking about. There is basically no reason whatsover to expect any consistency of behaviour between things that are so different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably because they were not designed with the same goals in mind.

The servlet API is a simple API, very close to the HTTP protocol, on top of which you can build applications or frameworks. The HTTP protocol being completely stateless, I guess it made sense to also build an API that is stateless. Several frameworks built on top of the servlet API (Stripes, for example), use one instance of Action per request, which is not used concurrently.

EJBs are a much more complex and high-level framework, designed to implement transactional business-logic as simply as possible. It's more heavyweight, and has stateful components. These obviously need to be thread-safe. I guess it was thus natural to make stateless beans thread-safe as well.

It should be noted that Spring beans, for example, are singletons by default, and must thus follow the same rules as servlets. So multiple designs are possible to provide more or less the same functionality.

Threads have nothing to do with a performance optimization. If you need to handle 3 requests concurrently, you need 3 threads, whether the request goes to a servlet or to an EJB.

Comment: Both both Servlets and EJBs can begin/commit transactions and as of Java EE 6 both can be multi-threaded.  It really was a matter of the EJB expert group being more conservative with the same decisions than the Servlet expert group -- until the last few years that is.  In EJB 3.2 we're totally getting rid of that bogus "can't use files" restriction that never should have been more than a recommendation and should have been in the EE spec rather than the EJB spec.

Comment: Thanks JB for the detailed explanation. I understand that Servlets are generally light-weight as compare to EJBs. But on the other hand, stateless EJBs (which are most common type of EJBs) provide the similar functionality and is not suppose to store any state. Similar to servlets, EJBs can easily be written in a manner to be 'Thread-safe'. Since, this is doable, creating threads is much more performance effective than creating instances. Is not that right?

Comment: First of all, stateless beans can have state. They can't have conversational state, which is very different. Second, as David Blevins explains in his answer, you may use singletons, which are similar to servlets. Third, threads are used in EJBs and servlets to handle concurrent requests. The only difference is that a single servlet instance is used by all the concurrent threads, whereas an EJB is only used by one thread at a time. Why makes you think creating a bean instance is so costly? Creating an object in Java is many orders of magnitude faster than executing a SQL query, for example.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet. I have multiple questions: 1) The state that stateless EJB's has is very similar to servlets (Is that right?). 2) I understand that cost of sql is too much as compare to creating an EJB instance, but industry and the application container tries to optimize it as much as possible and hence the servlet threads (is that right?) though it has negative effect that developers has to be careful.

Comment: Threads have nothing to do with a performance optimization. If you need to handle 3 requests concurrently, you need 3 threads, whether the request goes to a servlet or to an EJB. Servlets are singletons (only one instance created), and EJBs aren't (multiple instances created). But the cost of creating instances is probably not what led to the design of those two APIs. Singleton servlets are handy for many situations, and don't cause much implementation problems. Singleton EJBs are more problematic, especially stateful ones (impossible to implement as singletons), hence they're not singletons.

Comment: Ok. That is a nice explanation. Can you extend you answer little more and mention the design reason for Singleton servlet. I assumed performance of "Not creating objects, but threads" is the main and probably only reason. From your explanation, it seems it is not.

Answer (score 10):

The shortest answer to your question is of course it is a good idea to make it possible for EJBs to work like Servlets and in EJB 3.1 we added a component that can do exactly that: `@Singleton`

An `@Singleton` bean can be multi-threaded like a servlet, by either:

- Using `@ConcurrencyManagement(BEAN)`
- Using `@ConcurrencyManagement(CONTAINER)` along with `@Lock(READ)` on methods where concurrency is desired and `@Lock(WRITE)` on methods that are not thread safe.

One other thing that Servlets have had for years that EJBs never had was `<load-on-startup>` which allows a Servlet to load eagerly and do work at application start.

To match the Servlet `<load-on-start>` we added the `@Startup` annotation which can be added to any `@Singleton` EJB and will cause it to start when the application starts.  These beans will have their `@PostConstruct` method called when the application starts and their `@PreDestroy` called when the application shuts down.

Rather than use a number (`<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>`) to dictate the order in which beans annotated with `@Startup` start, you can annotate beans with `@DependsOn` and specify a list of beans that need to start before the annotated bean.

And a far less known and understood aspect we did in EJB 3.1 to align Servlets and EJBs was of course to allow EJBs to be packaged inside of `.war` files -- that's not the less known part -- and when we did that we quietly changed the definition of `java:comp/env` to match the Servlet approach.

Prior to EJB 3.1 there was no possible way to have two EJBs share a `java:comp/env` namespace (`java:comp/env` is bean-scoped in the EJB spec).  Servlets, by contrast, never had any way for individual Servlets to have their own private `java:comp/env` namespace (`java:comp/env` is module-scoped in the Servlet spec).  So in EJB 3.1 an EJB that is packed in a war will have the same module-scoped `java:comp/env` namespace as all other Servlets and EJBs in the webapp, which is a pretty big contrast to the bean-scoped `java:comp/env` namespace that EJBs get when packed in an EAR outside of a war.  We debated on that one for weeks.

Nice little bit of beer-time trivial to quiz your friends with.

Comment: This is great news to me that EJB in JEE6 is providing the option of multiple threads. This makes me happy that my understanding is on right track :)

Answer (score 3):

Your best answer is straight out of the Javadoc for the [javax.servlet.SingleThreadedModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/SingleThreadModel.html) interface:

> **Deprecated.** As of Java Servlet API 2.4, with no direct replacement.
>
> `public interface SingleThreadModel`
>
> Ensures that servlets handle only one request at a time. This interface has no methods.
>
> If a servlet implements this interface, you are *guaranteed* that no two threads will execute concurrently in the servlet's service method. The servlet container can make this guarantee by synchronizing access to a single instance of the servlet, or by maintaining a pool of servlet instances and dispatching each new request to a free servlet.
>
> Note that SingleThreadModel *does not solve all thread safety issues*. For example, session attributes and static variables can still be accessed by multiple requests on multiple threads at the same time, even when SingleThreadModel servlets are used. It is recommended that a developer take other means to resolve those issues instead of implementing this interface, such as avoiding the usage of an instance variable or synchronizing the block of the code accessing those resources. This interface is deprecated in Servlet API version 2.4.